# Accessing ModelForm queryset Object field in template

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

In my ModelForm, I am filtering the project_users to a certain set of all Users. How can I customize the checkboxes to show a users first_name and last_name?

Currently showing their email address as the checkbox label.

models.py

```
class Project(models.Model):
    project_business_profile = models.ForeignKey(BusinessProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    project_users = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='project_users')
    ...

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.project_name)
```

views.py

```
class EditProject(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    login_url = '/signin'
    redirect_field_name = 'signin'

    def get(self, request, project_id):
        ...
        form = EditProjectForm(instance=project)
        ...
```

forms.py

```
class EditProjectForm(ModelForm):
    project_users = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
                    widget = forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
                    queryset = User.objects.none()
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ['project_users']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(EditProjectForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        current_project = self.instance
        current_business = current_project.project_business_profile
        users = current_business.business_users.all()
        self.fields['project_users'].queryset = current_business.business_users.all() 
        // Spits out the correct users however I need to access other user fields of User in template. Name etc
```

template

```
{{form.as_p}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure I understand, do you just want to change the label which shows your user? If so something like this may work:

**forms.py**

```
class EditProjectForm(ModelForm):
    project_users = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
                    widget = forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
                    queryset = User.objects.none()
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ['project_users']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(EditProjectForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        current_project = self.instance
        current_business = current_project.project_business_profile
        users = current_business.business_users.all()
        self.fields['project_users'] = UserChoiceField(queryset=users)
        // Spits out the correct users however I need to access other user fields of User in template. Name etc

class UserChoiceField(forms.ModelChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        user = User.objects.get(id=obj.id)
        return user.get_full_name()
```